# Testing PopUpMenu with Robolectric

Tags: android, junit, kotlin, android-testing, robolectric

I have an Image on click of which I display a PopUpMenu. I am not getting any way to test that particular pop up menu that is being displayed.

I have two buttons 1) Edit , 2) Delete and what I want to test is the click of the Delete and the edit.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowPopupMenu;
import android.view.Menu;
import static android.view.Menu.FLAG_ALWAYS_PERFORM_CLOSE; 

... 

PopupMenu latestPopupMenu = ShadowPopupMenu.getLatestPopupMenu();
Menu menu = latestPopupMenu.getMenu();
menu.performIdentifierAction(R.id.edit_menu_item, FLAG_ALWAYS_PERFORM_CLOSE);
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much! I don't understand why doesn't answer marked as correct one though.